# Javascript async await with Promise all and fetch returning [object promise]

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Could someone explain to me why the expected result is an [object promise] and not return? help me please :(

```
'class Conexao {
  constructor(loading) {
    this.loading = loading;
  }


  acessar(rota) {
    return this.requisicao(rota, 1);
  }


  async requisicao(rota, id) {

    let rotas = ['https://willianjusten.com.br/search.json']
    rotas.push(rota);

    await Promise.all(rotas.map(function(url) {
      fetch(url).then(function(resp) {
        return resp.json();
      }).then(function(r) {
        return r;
      })
    }));    

  }
}

let conn = new Conexao(true);
let result_final = conn.acessar('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/');
console.log(result_final);`
```

https://jsbin.com/gekineneci/1/edit?js,console

Comment: The purpose of async/await functions is to simplify the behavior of using promises synchronously and to perform some behavior on a group of Promises. Just as Promises are similar to structured callbacks, async/await is similar to combining generators and promises.

Comment: It's the async return pattern, it always returns a promise.

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro Então.. isso que não estou entendendo muito bem. Se eu tiro o async await da funcao requisicao e deixo apenas a Promise.all, o retorno é undefined. PQ? Realmente não estou conseguindo compreender.

Comment: So .. this I'm not understanding very well. If I take the await async from the requesting function and just leave the Promise.all, the return is undefined. Why? I really can not understand.

Comment: @RafaelPelizza, please, make this same question at [StackOverflow PT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), there I can explain to you everything clearly in portuguese, send the link here after posting.

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/299973/javascript-func%C3%A3o-1-esperar-retorno-da-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-2-sync-await-promise-all

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> async requisicao(rota, id) {
> ```

You marked the function as `async`.

`async` functions always return promises.

See also [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).